# Find values of suPHP variables (ie. ${HOME}, ${USERNAME}, ${GROUPNAME}…)

Tags: logging, suphp

I keep getting 500 (Internal Server Error) and I suspect this is because I am setting docroot to `docroot=${HOME}*`. I want to 'peek under the hood' because I suspect `${HOME}` is what is causing the problems. How can I do this, or at least write all the variables to log whenever there is a problem.

**EDIT** I am using suPHP version 0.7.1-1 which does support variables within `docroot`

**EDIT** I tried cheating by appending the `${HOME}` variable to the log file name. For simplicity, I used the `${UID}` variable since `${HOME}` might have forward slashes in it. I updated the below line in the `/etc/suphp/suphp.conf` file

```
logfile=/var/log/suphp/suphp${UID}.log
```

I get the following file

```
/var/log/suphp/suphp${UID}.log
```

It's as if the `${UID}` variable does not even exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arises out of the fact that the `*` pattern in regular expressions here does not match `/`. Furthermore, the `*` is not even necessary since `docroot` will automatically include all recursive files. All I had to do was change

```
docroot=${HOME}*
```

to

```
docroot=${HOME}
```